# Downloading mp4 file for stream with selenium WebDriver on PHP

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I using PHP selenium webdriver for automation.
In remote server we have mp4 file that on click play it stream video to the browser.

How can i catch the video and save to file?

```
use Facebook\Webdriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeDriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverException;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebElement;
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverExpectedCondition;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Webdriverpoint;

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub';
$driver->get("http://example.com");

$vid = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath('videojs_html5'))->getAttribute("src");

//here need to save source to file
```

I have tried with fopen and file_get_contents, both not able to get the mp4 stream file.